# Ionic won't install

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, npm-install

I would like to ask you for help. I have problem with installatio of Ionic. Tried also with admin rights.

My steps:

```
npm uninstall ionic -g 
npm uninstall cordova -g 
npm cache clean
npm install minimatch -g
npm install cordova -g 
npm install ionic -g
```

This is output of bash:

```
$ npm install -g ionic@latest
C:\Users\Michal\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> C:\Users\Michal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Michal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\nan\package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Michal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\nan\package.json'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Michal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\nan\package.json'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\Michal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\node_modules\\nan\\package.json\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Michal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\node_modules\\nan\\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Michal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-10T09_59_33_279Z-debug.log

$ node -v
v8.4.0

$ npm -v
5.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to reboot and then replace all child permissions in `./node_modules/` so as to inherit from the parent. The error was telling me it was a permission error so replacing all files/folders permissions with my own user with full control worked for me (obviously, this was Windows in my case).

I wonder if i could have just deleted `./node_modules/`...